# What browsers are currently supporting E4X(to give direct support for XML to JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, e4x

I heard E4X; a New extension to the javascript gives direct support for XML to JavaScript.

Please tell me currently what browsers have  support for this.

Comment: FWIW, it's not a new extension; it's been an ECMA standard since 2004, it's just that nobody besides Mozilla seems to want to adopt it into production browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> E4X is supported by Mozilla's Rhino, used in OpenOffice.org and several other projects, and SpiderMonkey, used in Firefox, Thunderbird, and other XUL-based applications. It is also supported by Tamarin, the JavaScript engine used in the Flash virtual machine. It is not supported by Nitro (Safari), V8 (Google Chrome), Opera, nor Internet Explorer.

Comment: Things have changed and the support of e4x has been removed from Mozilla's products (it went obsolete like 2 or 3 years ago). Cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X :)